# Do I need to/can I free a void pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, void, void-pointers

I have a void pointer as a parameter for a function. It is currently pointing to an int. When I try to free it, it returns a bus error. Should I be freeing void pointers? If so, how do I do so?

Comment: Was it previously allocated with `malloc` or something like that?

Comment: @tadman No. It wasn't

Comment: If it wasn't returned by a function from the `malloc()` family somewhere along the line, you can't free it.

Comment: @Serket There's your problem.  Only pointers returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` may be passed to `free`.

Comment: @dbush so I don't need to do anything with it?

Comment: @Serket Not if it wasn't `malloc`'ed

Comment: Why do you have a `void*` pointing to an `int` ? Why would you free that?

Comment: @WeatherVane because I'm passing an int as the argument for a pthreads function

Comment: Rule of a thumb, there should be 1 free for every 1 call to malloc.

Comment: You do not allocate or free pointers. You allocate or free memory. If the pointer is pointing to memory that was allocated, then free the memory when you no longer need it. If it is not pointing to memory that was allocated, then there is nothing to be freed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to answer two questions first:

- Was it previously allocated with a `malloc` family function (e.g. `calloc`)?
- Did you inherit ownership of it when making the function call?

If the answer to both of those is "Yes", then it's at your discretion, though presumably you'd do it at the appropriate time and place to avoid "use after free" type bugs.

When you inherit ownership of a pointer you inherit the responsibility for calling `free()` when you're done using it, or passing on ownership to another part of your code. If you fail in this responsibility you have memory leaks.

As a general rule you should **never** `free()` a pointer unless you know with certainty that's what you're supposed to do, and you're allowed to do it.

Some functions return pointers to things that you do not own, and even if you did, they're not valid for `free()` because they may be offset somehow. Only the original pointer returned from the `malloc`-type function can be used with `free()`.

For example:

```
void* getBuffer(size_t size) {
  globalBufferOffset += size;
  return &globalBuffer[globalBufferOffset];
}
```

This returns a pointer in the middle of some structure that may or may not be dynamically allocated. You don't own it. You should not call `free()` on it.

**Read the documentation very carefully** to understand your responsibilities. You may need to call a special free-type function when you're done with the pointer. You may not. You may need to pay attention to thread safety. There's a lot of things that can be going on here you need to be aware of before making a decision.

Comment: @TonyTannous That's how you keep track of what part of your code is responsible for calling `free()`. It's implied in a lot of cases, or when someone's careful enough to document it, made express.

Comment: Great answer. Most important part is "Read the documentation very carefully to understand your responsibilities."

Answer (score 2):

If the pointer is allocated by `malloc` or something like that, you have to free. 
Because, the `malloc` function returns the `void *` pointer, so YES, you can/need to free this pointer.

There are some cases you should not free, for example, the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    void *p1, *p2, *p3;
    int x, y;

    p1 = &x;
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    p3 = malloc(10);
    *(int*)p2 = y;
    p3 = "abc";

    free(p1); // it raises the fault because p1 is not allocated by malloc 
    free(p2); // it's OK
    free(p3); // it raises also the fault because p3 points to string literal

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a corresponding `delete` each `new` or a `free` for each `malloc`.
If you never wrote a new or a malloc you don't need a free.

Some libraries have their own version of new and free. They would also have corresponding methods and hopefully some documentation. Like `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` and `SDL_FreeSurface`.